# Ignore the slash in Magento <url>

Tags: url, magento, slash

I’ve created a menu in page.xml and it looks like this:

```
<reference name="primary.menu">
<action method="addLink" translate="label title">
<label>Test</label>
<url>test.html</url>
<title>Test</title>
<prepare>1</prepare>
<urlParams/>
<position>10</position>
<liParams>dark-gray</liParams>
<aParams></aParams>
<beforeText></beforeText>
<afterText></afterText>
</action>
...................
```

The class used for the primary.menu block is extending the Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links class from Magento’s core.

The problem is, that when I click this link it goes to ‘www.mydomain.com/test.html/’ which is not working. My question is what should I do in order to stop the last ‘/’ from showing in the url?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that `<prepare>1</prepare>` is building your URL query (in the absence of a dedicated helper to supply the URL) and as a result is prefixing your URL with the domain (which is what you want), but it is also appending a trailing slash (which is what you don't want)

1. Either create a helper to supply the "proper" URL.
2. If the page is a Magento CMS page, use that helper **(preferred)**
3. Use `<prepare/>` and `<url>/test.html</url>` *(hack alert!)*

#### To use a Magento CMS helper to add a link

```
<action method="addLink" translate="label title before_text" module="cms">
  <label>Test</label>
  <url helper="cms/page/getPageUrl">
    <page_id>1</page_id>
  </url>
  <title>Test</title>
  <prepare/>
  <urlParams/>
  <position>10</position>
  <li/>
  <a/>
  <before_text/>
  <after_text/>
</action>
```